# Difference between GHC's -O and -O2

Tags: optimization, haskell, compiler-construction, ghc

`cabal dist` discourages you from using `-O2` since it produces longer compile times and the GHC manual says:

> At the moment, `-O2` is unlikely to produce better code than `-O`.

I know that I can always benchmark the library to see if `-O2` gives better performance, but I was wondering if somebody could explain what `-O2` does different from `-O` so I could get an intuition for why they consider it unlikely to produce better code.

Comment: The only way in which `-O2` may still be unlikely to produce better code than `-O` would be that code where the difference is significant or perhaps present at all might be rare - no idea whether it is. Sometimes it makes a huge difference, cf. my comment on Don's answer. I recommend using `-O2` unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-O2` performs the constructor specialization. There are some other optimizations that are only enabled at -O2 as well, including `-fliberate-case`, `-fstatic-argument-transformation`,

I have a suspicion that -O2 now always produces better code, since that recommendation dates back about 10 years.

Comment: Not always, there's a lot of code where there's no difference. But there's also a lot of code where `-O2` does significantly better than `-O`. For my prime sieve, it makes a 2.5× difference, for example (with ghc-7.4.2).

Comment: Not that I've done exhaustive tests, but I haven't seen a case where `-O2` does worse than `-O` for a while (pre-ghc7 I think).